# VB.NET Creating a local database in VS2013 or in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I am about to begin a personal project to build my skills in the .net environment. I am familiar with SQL Server Management Studio and how to create a database in it but I discovered how to make a local database in Visual Studio as well. My program is only going to require local database access as it will be used for individual inventory systems rather than connected ones. Am I ok to use the onboard tools in visual studio and create a local databasse or should I be using the SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the Local Database item template in VS, it creates a SQL Server CE data file (SDF) and adds it to your project.  When you use the Service-based Database item templete, it creates a SQL Server (Express) data file (MDF) and adds it to your project.

The advantage of using the VS tools is that the data file becomes part of your project and can therefore be easily deployed with the compiled application.  As such, the database is basically part of the application.

If you choose SQL Server CE then you don't need a server installed on the user's local machine.  They can install SQL Server CE or you can install it with your app if you want, but you also have the option of simply deploying a DLL with your app and it will work.

If you choose SQL Server Express then the user actually needs a SQL Server instance installed on their machine.  To be honest, I'm not 100% sure whether that instance must be SQL Server Express or it can be a full SQL Server instance too.  It would usually be SQL Server Express though, which you can install and even download automatically when you install your app, depending on the deployment method you choose.

If you use the VS tools to create an MDF data file then your connection string will contain the `Data Source` and `AttachDbFilename` attributes.  The `Data Source` will generally be ".\SQLExpress", i.e. an instance named "SQLExpress" on the local machine.  That instance name is not required, although it is the default for SQL Server Express, but it **must** be on the local machine.  The MDF file gets attached at run time and detached again when you're app is done with it.  It will also usually be attached to a user instance, which means that other users can't see it, even when it's attached.  Note that, in later versions, the LocalDB feature of SQL Server may also be utilised.

If you create your database in Management Studio then it's not actually part of your app.  It will be permanently attached to the SQL Server instance so, everyone will be able to see it and open it, assuming permissions allow.  Creating the database during deployment will be an extra step in that case.  You might create a backup and restore that during deployment or generate SQL scripts that get run.  In this case, your connection string will contain the `Initial Catalog` attribute to specify the name of database to connect to, as well as the `Data Source` attribute.  This option is required if you want multiple clients to be able to connect to the database.

In short, if you are only going to be accessing a database from the local instance of the one application then creating a database in VS is OK and probably a good idea.  Whether you choose SQL Server CE or SQL Server Express may well depend on what level of functionality you need.

Comment: Is that last sentence from reference able please? I was wondering if you got the the "Note that, in later versions, the LocalDB feature of SQL Server may also be utilised." from a URL and if one please

Comment: @PreetSangha, sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking.  If you're asking about LocalDB then start reading here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-AU?query=localdb&emptyWatermark=true&ac=2

Comment: Thankyou very much for this detailed response it was exactly what I was looking for and helped clarify things immensely.